# HTTPS for Elastic Beanstalk (AWS) running Python Flask application. Unable to get URL to resolve

Tags: python, ssl, flask, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a small Python site using the Flask framework. I've uploaded it to AWS using Elastic Beanstalk, and attempted to configure the environment to ensure HTTPS is enabled. I have done this previously with ASP.NET and IIS, but not Python / Apache. (I'm VERY new to this 'stack').  If I visit the underlying elastic beanstalk URL I can visit the site fine (try for yourself)

http://flask-priceline.f8n9uir55a.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com

However when I try to visit the proper DNS with either HTTPS or HTTP, e.g.

http://plmonitoring.in-daws.api.net.au/ or https://plmonitoring.in-daws.api.net.au/

I get:

*This site can’t be reached plmonitoring.in-daws.api.net.au’s server IP address could not be found.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN*

Here is what I've done. I have a valid certificate already created in AWS. I've also set up the appropriate record set(s)/CNAMES in Route 53 so that my alias points to the load balancer I have created.

I have created my Elastic Beanstalk environment with a classic load balancer. The load balancer is in a public subnet, the EC2 instance running the web server is in the private subnet. (This VPC is pre-existing and is configured correctly).  I have created the following Listeners on the load balancer:

[image]

I've done this via the following .ebextensions config file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elb:listener:443:
    SSLCertificateId: arn:aws:acm:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxx:certificate/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ListenerProtocol: HTTPS
    InstancePort: 80
```

I also have the following set up in my security groups (I've tried adding HTTP 80 as inbound to Load Balancer and outbound to EC2/inbound to EC2 as well without change). This is the load balancer security group inbound:

[image]

Load balancer Out:

[image]

EC2 In:

[image]

EC2 Out:

[image]

I also added this sample to the .ebextensions folder in the hopes it would redirect HTTP to HTTPS in case the user typed in HTTP instead of HTTPS - https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/python/https-redirect-python.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Human error of the worst kind. Set the Record Set up as IPV4, NOT CNAME!. Problem solved.